# Delta plane looked like it was landing on Atlanta freeway

Tags: landing

Yesterday a few minutes after 4:00pm ET (2020-01-04 21:00 UTC) I drove my car out of Park-Ride Lot C of Hartsfield-Jackson Atlanta International Airport in Atlanta and took 85 South to 285 West/North.

[image: map]

When I reached the 285 N part of my drive, a southbound airliner was descending straight toward me, and since Hartsfield doesn't have north-south runways, I immediately felt like something was "off".

Having lived in San Diego for many years (which has an airport VERY close to the city) and also Atlanta for many years, I'm used to seeing jets come in for landings.

But this felt different.

So I thought "Maybe it's a military plane, and maybe there is an Air Force base nearby with a north-south runway"... I was grasping for an explanation.) But I clearly read Delta on the belly of the plane, so Hartsfield must have been its destination.

It felt so much closer than any other jet in my years of living in the Atlanta area that I went home and felt certain I'd find news stories about a Delta jet landing on an Atlanta freeway, but I haven't found any.

I can think of 2 possible answers:

- Maybe I was still on the parts of 85 S and 285 W that travel west, and the plane was flying east and landing on the [southernmost runway (10)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartsfield%E2%80%93Jackson_Atlanta_International_Airport#/media/File:ATL_airport_diagram.svg). And maybe this particular plane just happened to be coming in lower than any other I've ever seen but within their own expectations for minimum altitude.

  - But I *really think* that I'd already made it to the part of 285 N that travels nearly due north (shown on the left side of the map).
- Maybe there are tiny stretches of 285 N/W that travel due west for a long enough time that an aircraft landing on one of the other runways would have been facing me head-on.

  - But I think Google Maps is really accurate, and even when zooming in, I see no part of the 285 N freeway west of the airport that would have taken me due west.

Would there be any *other* explanation?

Comment: You should edit the title to be a question as this is standard on yhis Q&A website

Comment: Since you only "really think" that you had made a turn to the north, I would vote for the first of your possible explanations.  There are a lot of turns just getting to the freeway, I would bet that you got twisted around and perceived the turn from S/SW to W as the turn from W to N/NW, and were actually further back that you realized.  It happens to me all the time, one turn looks very much like the next, and you realize you aren't as far along as you thought.

Comment: Two things. One, that area of I-85 and I-285 is extremely confusing, and I frequently can't tell which cardinal direction I'm facing when going through it. Second, if you did see a plane flying perpendicular to the normal flow of traffic, the plane may have been "going around" because they aborted the landing.

Comment: I don't think there is a right answer to this, all we can do is speculate.  I have seen questions closed for less...

Comment: “Yesterday a few minutes after 4:00pm ET”—did I derive the date correctly to 2020-01-04 16:00-05:00, converted to UTC as 2020-01-04 21:00Z?

Comment: I've replayed 2020-01-04 20:45Z to 2020-01-04 22:00 on [FlightRadar24](https://www.flightradar24.com/2020-01-04/20:45/12x/33.64,-84.46/13) and seen nothing but a completely regular flow of western traffic with active runways 27 and 28.

Comment: @MichaelHall, well, we can find the aircraft in question on flightradar. But I saw none. if I had the time corect—the question should state date, not “yesterday”, because the post is going to stay for many days and it won't be “yesterday” tomorrow anymore.

Comment: @Jan Hudec, good point, I didn't think about replaying FlightRadar24!  Your findings do confirm my hypothesis though.

Comment: @JanHudec Correct, 2020-01-04 21:00 UTC. Thanks for pointing me to that really useful site; I'd accept it as an answer! I filtered to only planes in the air and must have callsign with "DAL" since it was a Delta jet. I see DAL695 with estimated arrival of 16:16 ET, but that one flew east (not south) and did not even land on the southernmost runway (which would be closest to 285 West), so that couldn't be it because it's not flying along freeways southbound or eastbound, so I wouldn't have thought it was about to land on one. This site hasn't shown me a Delta plane tracing a freeway yet…

Comment: @MichaelHall and Jan: How strange is *this*? https://imgur.com/a/dAF8exK  DAL695 (N389DA) is shown as this red plane flying *westbound* https://www.flightradar24.com/2020-01-04/21:12/12x/DAL695/2369833d over runway 27L at 21:13 UTC and then seems to *hover* for a moment before immediately bouncing eastbound to land at runway 09L. That would be impossible, so I wonder if I don't know how to use this flightradar24 site.

Comment: @Ryan, when the ADS-B receiver misses a squawk from the plane, the position is estimated according to the last known velocity vector. As the data dropped just as the plane slowed down and turned off the runway, the interpolation made it to appear to overshoot the runway, and then return back when next valid position report arrived. That kind of error appears on FR24 all the time.

Comment: @JanHudec If I understand you correctly, this means that DAL695 was landing from the east (facing west) and was definitely not the plane I saw somewhere *over the freeway west of Hartsfield*. And FR24 didn't show *any* Delta planes during that time range that could have been the one. How odd.

Comment: @Ryan, indeed it wasn't and indeed I've seen no aircraft there that could match the position you describe, not just Delta ones, but none at all.

Comment: Was the aircraft's landing gear down? If not, I'd posit that you more likely saw a _departure_ from 27R. Those often begin a turn somewhat toward the South around the time they get to 285. They aren't flying _due_ South parallel to the Interstate, but they do turn to something like West Southwest. Perhaps the banking for the turn made its path appear more parallel to the I-285 than it really was? Granted, these generally aren't flying at especially low, though heavier ones might be somewhat low at that point (and also might look lower, but are really just bigger.)

Comment: @reirab Thanks for these thoughts. *Probably* the landing gear was down, because I remember thinking "It's going to land on the freeway", and I'd have far less of a chance of thinking that if it looked like it was taking off. This sure is one of those times when I wish I had a dashboard camera.

Comment: @Ryan If it was a departure (which would make the most sense for being on that side of the field at that time, due to the airport being in West flow,) another reason that a Heavy could have been relatively low is noise abatement procedures. Sometimes (including at ATL,) they pull the power back after they're comfortably airborne in order to reduce noise until they get high enough and/or far enough away from heavily-populated areas, then spool back up to normal climb power.

Comment: @reirab +1 It's cool that you know all this. But it's still not making sense to me. It seems like you're saying it could have taken off westward from 26R and then immediately made a >90-degree turn southbound (while still very low to the ground) while I was driving north on 285 N. But I don't see anything like that on [flightradar24](https://www.flightradar24.com/2020-01-04/20:45/12x/33.64,-84.46/13).

Comment: @Ryan I don't think it would have been > 90 degrees by the time it got to 285 (more like ~20-30 degrees,) but maybe it looked more parallel to 285 than it really was? The only aircraft I saw on FR24 at that time that were actually a reasonable approximation of parallel to 285 were all the way up at cruise altitude. But a heavy jet would make the most sense for being and appearing low, though, due to the combination of reduced power for noise abatement, longer takeoff run and slower climb due to weight, and also just looking lower than they really are because of their massive size.

Comment: @reirab I tried finding a site other than FR24 and found https://planefinder.net/flight/DAL1604/time/2020-01-04T21:15:00.000Z/speed/20 but don't see any plane in the time range that was oriented how I saw. I'm sure I look crazy by this point.